# How to create index to optimize a "Key Lookup"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-azure

I have an SP which on first run, can run for over a minute.  On second run, it takes less than a second.

To fix, I check the Execution Plan which shows this:

[image: Execution Plan]

[image: Details]

So I add the following index, which as far as I know should create an index so it doesn't use the Key Lookup:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_account_id_include_utility_id] 
ON dbo.account (account_id)
 include ( utility_id)
```

I create the index which took 1 min 50 seconds.

I then check the execution plan again.  But it has exactly the same plan with the Key Lookup.

Am I doing something wrong here with the index?

I am a newbie at indexing and optimization, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the query inside the sproc and [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keylookup means that a specific field is not available in the index and we have to go to the data page to pick up the field.

In your case, `accountid` is being used to pickup the `utility_id` from the data page of `Account` table.

What you have to do is, add this utility_id as part of the included column of either of the right most two indexes (as highlighted in Right box), to avoid the key lookup.

[image]

But, in your case, you are again adding the index to the `account` table. So, it is not leveraging the newly created index.

Comment: Thank you, I added it to the CustId index and you are correct, it then used that index instead of the Key Lookup.

Comment: Happy to note. Glad it helped.